# I need to change "h2 class" in the logo for the seo

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, css, phtml, seo

I know where magento put the phtml and css file but i don't know css style.

An SEO expert, told me to remove the h2 from their.
The problem is that in the theme, the h2 has a style applied

How can I change this parameter to maintain this style ?

Comment: Have you searched the CSS file for the styles that are associated to the H2 tag?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the h2 tags from the Theme. Before, install a extension like FireBug to try in your Browser. You had to change css definitions if your logo is not displayed on the correct position.